# How do I dock Table of Contents in Books on macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, books

I am on macOS Mojave 10.14.2 and using Books Version 1.16(1636.1).

When I am reading a book, the table of contents can be only shown on demand and in auto-hide mode.

Is there a way to dock it?

Comment: so you want the TOC to show permanently in Dock  ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes I would like to dock it on left side

Comment: I am looking for the same.  I would like to dock it on left side permanently